Исключение xstring boost.asio
У меня есть клиент-серверная архитектура. В логике сервера создается класс Session под каждого нового подключившегося клиента. В классе Session имеется shared_ptr на класс CommunicationHandler который отвечает за методы общения с клиентом ( sendPacket, recvPacket и прочие )
Так выглядит CommunicationHandler.h:
#pragma once
#ifndef COMMUNICATION_HANDLER_H
#define COMMUNICATION_HANDLER_H

#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class CommunicationHandler : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CommunicationHandler>
{
public:
    CommunicationHandler(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket);

    void test();

private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
};

#endif // !COMMUNICATION_HANDLER_H

CommunicationHandler.cpp:
#include "communicationhandler.h"

CommunicationHandler::CommunicationHandler(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
    : socket(std::move(socket)) {

}

void CommunicationHandler::test() {
    std::string string = "hello, client";

    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(this->socket, boost::asio::buffer(string), [self](boost::system::error_code errorCode, std::size_t bytes) {

    });
}

При попытке использовать метод test() я получаю исключение

Я плохо разбираюсь в умных указателях и во времени жизни объектов, имею только малое представления об этих понятиях поэтому решить данный вопрос самому не получается.
p.s передача числовых значений не вызывает никаких исключений, клиент получает данные

это я понимаю, а как тогда решить проблему с существованием string?

void CommunicationHandler::test() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());

    std::string string = "hello, client";
    // Создаем временный буфер, копируя данные из локальной переменной string
    auto buffer = std::make_shared<std::string>(string);
    
    boost::asio::async_write(this->socket, boost::asio::buffer(*buffer), [self, buffer (boost::system::error_code errorCode, std::size_t bytes) {

    });
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
